# I want to Send FCM notification using python

Tags: python, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

i want to send fcm notification to topic using just python

```
from pyfcm import FCMNotification

API_KEY = "AAAA...Gzzjo"


push_service = FCMNotification(api_key=API_KEY)

data = {'notification': {'title': 'Test','body': 'first test'}
        , 'data':{'click_action':'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'}}

print(push_service.notify_topic_subscribers(topic_name="topicname", data_message=data))
```

but the notification didn't send to the topic and keep showing me this

```
{'multicast_ids': [], 'success': 1, 'failure': 0, 'canonical_ids': 0, 'results': [], 'topic_message_id': 4051394435713630091}
```

any solution ?

Comment: jsonify the data before sending it. That should work.

Comment: No it didn't work

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: did you find any solution ?